# How to extract every nth row from dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

that looks like this (skipping over many rows):

```
       id    
201    1
202    2
203    3
301    4
303    5
401    6
```

I only want to pick every index that is `x01st` meaning that want rows that are 201, 301, 401, 501, for the entire dataframe.

I tried this :

```
if df.index % 100 = 1:
    not sure what to do
```

Comment: Do you want omit `1.` and `101.` row ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, need for default `RangeIndex` compare by `1`:

```
df1 = [df.index % 100 == 1]
```

Solution with general index:

```
df1 = [np.arange(len(df)) % 100 == 1]
```

If want also omit `1.` and `101.` rows:

```
df2 = (df[(df.index % 100 == 1) & (df.index > 200)]
```

And:

```
a = np.arange(len(df))
df2 = df[(a % 100 == 1) & (a > 200)]
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
#print (df)

a = np.arange(len(df))
df2 = df[(a % 100 == 1) & (a > 200)]
print (df2)
     A  B  C
201  4  4  4
301  1  3  2
401  0  3  5
501  5  8  4
601  3  7  9
701  5  5  7
801  4  1  0
901  4  7  6
```